# User export collection to CSV

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, express

I have a collection (assets) inside a database (assetDB) and I want to have it so a use can click a button submitting a form that will allow them to download all documents inside a collection where they are the author of the document. I know I need a query somewhere with `"author.id":req.user.id` in it as the search param.

```
User.find({"author.id":req.user.id}, function(err, allUser) {
  if(err){
   console.log(err);
  } else {
    // export  allUser into CSV file                
  }
});
```

I found a package called [mongo-to-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-to-csv) but I am unsure how I would implement this in my route while getting only the results for the current user.

Comment: You can ask a question here that is essentially *"here is what I tried, but I cannot work out this part and need help"*. But you cannot ask for a straight up tutorial on how to do something from scratch as it's "too broad" a question. Also simply "mentioning" an library without actually showing your own usage attempt in the context of the question basically invites **"recommendations"**, which is also "off-topic".  So if you can modify your question to actually show "attempted usage" then that's okay. As a starter hint, you probably don't want "arrays" for result output if you are exporting.

Comment: @NeilLunn It is broad yes but that is because I am not even sure how to structure it. If I knew even the basics of how to do the export of the results of that query then I could piece it together but I am confused on how to implement this. I wish I could have been more specific but I can't until someone gives me a direction to go in then come back and iterate till I get it. I am not looking for a code copy but a direction on generally the steps even.

Comment: That's what the ["documentation"](https://github.com/yasharma/mongo-to-csv) and ["code examples in the repository"](https://github.com/yasharma/mongo-to-csv/tree/master/example) are for. You're still relatively new to posting here, so I'm just "informing" you of "how it is" and the [general guidelines of posting a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). So I suggest you read all those links ( especially the site guidelines ) if you want to stay "on topic" and continue to use the site "as intended". **Show some code** and if you are stuck on a point then happy to help.